# Rendering Video in 3ds Max 9 Custom 1280x720 didn't come out 16:9

Tags: 3d, animation, 3ds-max, video

Ok I tried a few times rendering my 3d animation to video custom 1280x720, image aspect 1.778 pixel aspect 0.9. So far when you see it as it renders it appears to look fine, but after all the rendering was done and viewed the video on VLC it wasn't even the right size, it was 720x480 and the width appeared squeezed and didn't even fit right as 16:9. Did I do something wrong? I can't figure out why that happens, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a 3ds problem. You can solve it by rendering in frames (single photos, if you will) and compile it into a video afterwards. This has been a problem for years and they still haven't fixed it, unfortunately...

Comment: Very interesing. If it is a common 3ds problem, then why are people still using 3ds Max. Do you know of an application that can join all single images into a video?

Comment: Actually for my situation this one worked. Sure it didn't produce a video as a I wanted. It just got me to do more work to join all the single images into a video. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need the pixel aspect to be 1.

0.9 will squash it 10%. It basically means for every 10px vertically, it only covers 9 horizontally, causing the squash.

Comment: Hmm, this gives me an idea to try something. I will be back with some results. thanks.

Comment: I rendered it with 1.0 pixel aspect. still came out the same. I wonder how 16:9 can be achieved.

Comment: still came out the same. 720 x 480 instead of 1280 x 720. I even tried to be funny and made the pixel aspect 2.0 but still didn't work.

Comment: If you have it set to image aspect 1.778 and pixel aspect to 1.0, it should come out square pixels 16:9. If that doesn't work, take a look at your camera object settings, both the camera and render settings can affect the output.